# Handler losing WeakReference

Tags: android, android-intent, weak-references, android-handler

I have a handler which i send to an Intent Service to later receive the message and notify the UI. The problem that i have is that very fequently I'm loosing the weak reference and I'm unable to notify the Activity that i have received the information requested by the Intent service.

This is my class that holds the messenger:

```
public class UserManager extends Observable {

    MessengerHandler handler = new MessengerHandler(this);

    UserManager(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void find() {
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, UserIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(MESSENGER_KEY, messenger);
        mActivity.startService(intent);
    }

    static class MessengerHandler extends Handler {

        private final WeakReference<UserManager> outerClass;

        public MessengerHandler(UserManager outer) {
            outerClass = new WeakReference<UserManager>(outer);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            if (outerClass.get() == null) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Weak reference lost, impossible to notify UI");
                return;
            }

            outerClass.get().setChanged();
            outerClass.get().notifyObservers();
        }
    }
}
```

and the onHandle Intent:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt(CloudManager.REQUEST_CODE_KEY, intent.getIntExtra(CloudManager.REQUEST_CODE_KEY, 0));
    msg.setData(data);

    try {
        messenger.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Weak reference objects, which do not prevent their referents from being made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed" [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

Comment: your `UserIntentService` is a local `Service` so there is no need for using a `Messenger`, `ResultReceiver` or any othe similar mechanism, just use a "local bound service" pattern